# Using Laravel to fetch data for Kendo Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, kendo-ui

I am able to pull data out from my database using laravel and send it back to kendo autocomplete.

The problem I have is that I am getting the error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I have a feeling that is because the data being returned is in the wrong format i.e.:

```
{"16159":"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"}
```

When it should be somethind like

```
[{"id": 16159, "name":"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"}, *other counties...*]
```

My Laravel code is:

```
public function getCities() {
        $Cities = new Cities;
        $cities = $Cities->where('accentName', 'LIKE', '%unite%')->orderBy('accentName', 'asc')->lists('accentName', 'id');
        return $cities;
    }
```

And my JS is:

```
$('input#cityAuto').kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "name",
    filter: "contains",
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: {
        type: "POST",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "apply/getCities"
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get Laravel to return the JSON string in the way that I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using `Response::json()` like below:

```
public function getCities() {
    $Cities = new Cities;
    $cities = $Cities->where('accentName', 'LIKE', '%unite%')->orderBy('accentName', 'asc')->lists('accentName', 'id');

    // to return json
    return Response::json($cities->toArray());

}
```